# How to check if a coordinate exists in GMSMutablePath before adding a coordinate

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to draw a polyline on the Google map as a object travels, sometimes the coordinates sent can get duplicated. I want to prevent duplicate coordinate from being added to the GMSMutablePath. Anyway this be achieved?

Currently I use the following method to add the coordinate to the GMSMutablePath. It adds duplicate values as well!

```
self.path.addLatitude(coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
```

Comment: You can keep the location in your array and when you get a new coordinate, check whether it is present in array or not. If present, simply make a break/return else add it to your `GMSMutablePath`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to minimize the memory usage. Dont want to have another array, as lots of coordinates will be needed to draw a polyline.

Comment: Generally we never get exactly the same coordinates (lat and long). There is some difference always. Only way to get the duplicate coordinate is when the location manager takes it from its cache.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari the coordinates come from another device, not a iOS device. It sends duplicate coordinates as well when its in one position. I'll have to try to handle that from that device I guess

Comment: Coordinates from different device? Couldn't get? You should handle the coordinates from your own device.

Comment: The coordinates which I add to the GMSMutablePath come from a GPS device, not a iOS device. Duplicate coordinates are sent from that device.

Comment: Kindly have a look at my answer and see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some digging in `GoogleMaps SDK`, I arrived at this solution. It may not be the perfect one but you can give it a try.

You can iterate through all the coordinates of the path by using `coordinate(at:index)` method of `GMSMutablePath`

Iterating the `GMSMutablePath` coordinates.

```
//Here path is your GMSMutablePath
for i in 0..<path.count() {
    let coordinate = path.coordinate(at: i)
    //The coordinate received is a CLLocationCoordinate2D type from which you can get the latitude and longitude.

    //Here check the coordinate latitude and longitude is same as your received coordinate, make a return else add to your path. 
    //You can also keep a flag variable and at the end of all iterations, you can check whether the coordinate is present or not. 

    print(coordinate)
}
```

Comment: in for loop Binary operator '..<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'UInt?'

Comment: @jayantrawat Can you show your code what is the issue